# Safari and SharePoint

Tags: safari, microsoft-sharepoint

The usual behaviour when opening a Document on SharePoint ist that the document is opened in the corresponding Web App. In my case it is simply downloaded (with Safari).

It was like that with OS X 10.8, than it was OK with some of the 10.9 versions and now is back to download only with 10.10.

It should not be version related as I know of machines with El Capitan where the behaviour is *normal* (open in browser).

Any idea what would make my browser act differently?

Comment: Is the share point mounted as an Internet drive?

Comment: No is not mounted

Comment: Try mounting it instead of accessing it through the webapp. It's not a direct solution, but it should provide some info.

Comment: Mounting works without problems. I can even download/edit and then upload. But it would be nice to have the default behavior